# Programmatically include curl request body in an edgeSDK microservice's http request

Tags: javascript, json, microservices, edgesdk, edgeengine

I'm trying to put together a small edgeSDK microservice operation that programmatically adds a body to the http request it makes so that the user doesn't have to do it manually as part of the curl command. At the moment, if I execute in a terminal, for example

```
curl -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getMe", "params": [""]}' http://localhost:8083/<BASE_API_PATH>/doStuff
```

as the API request, it works fine, but if I type

```
curl http://localhost:8083/<BASE_API_PATH>/doStuff
```

and try to have the operation's code programmatically add

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getMe", "params": [""]}
```

to the http request object, it has so far just returned a *404 - Not Found* error. Is there a way to programmatically add the body, or is including it in the curl command in the terminal the only way to include the body?

Here's (more or less) my code for trying to get this part of the microservice operation to work. I've tried various permutations of assigning the body to `request.body`, and to `data` in the object passed to `context.http.request()`, both as a string and as a JSON object. The most recent iterations are commented out in the code below.

```
app.post('/doStuff', (request, response) => 
{
    //const body = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getMe", "params": [""]}'));
    //const body = JSON.stringify({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getMe", "params": [""]});
    //const body = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getMe", "params": [""]}';
    //const body = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "getMe", "params": [""]};

    //request.body = body;

    context.http.request((
    {
        type: 'POST',
        //data: body,
        url: 'http://localhost:8083/jsonrpc/v1',
        success: function(r) 
        {
            //TODO: stuff

            response.end('Finally, it works');
        },
        error: function(err) 
        {
            response.end(err.message);
        }
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
    curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/<BASE_API_PATH>/doStuff
```

Because it is a POST request, so curl without explicit HTTP method might not work.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thank you.